# Best UI Framework for WinForms?

Tags: winforms, user-interface

Can someone suggest a good UI framework for WinForms development? What I'm looking for is something that is fairly mature (=bug-free), renders well and quickly, and does not bloat my program with 10Mb assemblies.

Comment: How about ... WinForms? What exactly is it that you need to do that the standard Windows Forms controls can't?

Answer (score 3):

Me and my team all use [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com). The result is a stunningly good looking GUI, the controls are very mature and easy to use.

I've purchased the developer express report control and it does not scale well at all. It maxes out the CPU on our webservers when producing a report with 10k+ rows on it. So I can't recommend developer express.

Answer (score 0):

I use developer express. IMHO cleaner more rational API than infragistics, fewer bugs with visual studio and help integration. I never look at the size of assemblies.. it's not a really useful metric for me in .net installs. Just to install hello world you are looking at massive downloads and long .net framework installs.

Comment: Unfortunately, after working with DevEx for 2 years, I decided it's not for me - this is the reason I'm asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest looking at DevExpress [WinForms UI library](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/) which ships with over 190 high-performance and fully customizable UI controls and over 50 amazing application themes.

DevExpress is the only UI component vendor to offer WinForms DirectX rendering support. By moving to DirectX, their controls have achieved the highest possible performance and brilliant High DPI rendering quality.

You can try all DevExpress products for 30 days for free at https://www.devexpress.com/try

Comment: I made the mistake of getting into DevExpress about 10 years ago, and the results, frankly, were terrible. It would take a whole blog post to describe what's wrong with DevExpress, let's just say I refactored an entire application away from it.

Comment: Well, that's long time ago. At the moment they have very fast and high-quality controls. Of course, not without bug issues, but they quickly fix them. By the way, did you contact their support team?

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider Nevron Open Vision for .NET (https://www.nevron.com/products-open-vision.aspx).

It contains 70+ UI components, plus advanced Chart, Grid, Diagram, Rich Text Editor, Gauge and Schedule components. All components can be integrated into any WinForms, WPF, Xamarin.Mac and Blazor - WebAssembly project.

The solution features hardware acceleration on most platforms (renders really fast), and is very lightweight.